# Magento API V2 Methods not found but are in WSDL (works on LIVE server but not DEV)

Tags: api, development, magento-enterprise

I'm trying to get the API system up and running for a third party but I have a problem whereby the API calls work fine on my local machine and the LIVE server but are refusing to work properly on the staging server.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in /shop/scripts/apiTest.php:26
Stack trace:
0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__call('magentoInfo', Array)
2 /shop/scripts/apiTest.php(26): SoapClient->magentoInfo('a97b51e10f65783...')
3 {main}
  thrown in /shop/scripts/apiTest.php on line 2
```

I've checked, double checked and triple checked (even using __getFunctions()) that the methods being called are there and available and also that the user being logged in as (which works fine and gives me a session ID) has access to the methods too. From what I can tell the server setups are identical too.

Any ideas? I'm starting to pull my hair out now and really need this working ASAP :(

====

Additionally, here's a sample of code from my apiTest.php file. It fails at the magentoInfo() call.

http://pastebin.com/H043Tr21

Comment: Check the `var/log` folder for errors. Also you can try to use a tool for API testing. I recommend SoapUI http://soapui.com/. It's more verbose than a simple php script.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the php wsdl cache? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303488/in-php-how-can-you-clear-a-wsdl-cache // you can also delete the cachefile - usually it's in /tmp

Comment: I've tried both of these unfortunately. The var/log folder isn't registering any errors (yes, logging is enabled).

I've even reloaded the codebase onto the server thats not functioning correctly in the hope that'd work.

Comment: Perhaps the API user on Staging lacks role permissions?  Difficult to try and reproduce without seeing what's in your `apiTest.php` script.

Comment: All three servers are set up with the same permissions for a user and role.

apiTest.php contains this to begin with. Nothing else will run as the first method call to magentoInfo fails.

Pastebin of the code here: http://pastebin.com/H043Tr21

Comment: Just out of curiosity what happens when you try using v1?  http://pastebin.com/Pt2aUyKs

Comment: did you sort this? I have the same issue, v1 SOAP also works fine but v2 doesn't..